# Change date format for specific cells in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am working with a big dataset (more than 2 million rows x 10 columns) that has a date column. Some of the rows are formatted correctly (e.g. 2020/04/08) but I want to change the format of others that are not (concretely, those are formatted as 20200408).

I want to change the format of those that are wrong but I don't want to iterate through all the rows.

Normally, for a small dataset I would do

```
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    cell=str(df.iloc[i]['date'])
    if len(cell)==8:
        df.iat[i, df.columns.get_loc('date')] = datetime.strptime(cell, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I know this is far from optimal.

How can I use the power of pandas to avoid the loop here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filter rows by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), then select column by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and mask, convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and last to custom format by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
m = df['date'].str.len() == 8
df.loc[m, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m, 'date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime())
```